# Why is the TypeScript parser expecting a comma?

Tags: typescript

My question relates to the following line of code:

```
                parser.on("headers", headers:any => console.log(`Message: ${headers.subject}`));
```

When trying to compile, I get:

hello_world.ts(49,45): error TS1005: ',' expected.

Where is the missing comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript tries to parse `headers` and `any` as different `parser.on` arguments, because arrow syntax is invalid.

It should be:

```
parser.on("headers", (headers:any) => console.log(`Message: ${headers.subject}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parser.on("headers", headers:any => console.log(`Message: ${headers.subject}`));
```

`headers:any` isn't valid typescript unless it's in a parameter or variable definition. The syntax parser can't tell in this context, so you need to give it a hint with parenthesis:

```
parser.on("headers", (headers: any) => console.log(`Message: ${headers.subject}`));
```